# Customising navigation bar in Xamarin iOS 13 not working

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, ios13

I am trying to customise navigation bar colour in iOS 13 for Xamarin but it's not working I have tried below code

```cs
if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(13, 0))          
{            
    var appearance = new UINavigationBarAppearance();
    appearance.ConfigureWithOpaqueBackground();
    appearance.BackgroundColor = Utility.ColorConstants.NavigationBarColor;               
    appearance.TitleTextAttributes = new UIStringAttributes() { ForegroundColor = UIColor.White };
    appearance.LargeTitleTextAttributes = new UIStringAttributes() { ForegroundColor = UIColor.White };

    UIBarButtonItem.Appearance.SetTitleTextAttributes(new UITextAttributes
    {
        TextColor = UIColor.White
    }, UIControlState.Normal);

    UINavigationBar.Appearance.ScrollEdgeAppearance = appearance;
    UINavigationBar.Appearance.StandardAppearance = appearance;
}
```

In app delegate class while launching the application I am calling the above code for setting the navigation bar appearance but its not working.

Please anybody facing this issue just help me for same.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom **navigationBar** as you want .

```
public class BaseViewController: UIViewController
{
  public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
  {
     base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
     NavigationController.NavigationBar.Hidden = true;

     double height = IsiphoneX();

     UIView backView = new UIView()
     {
         BackgroundColor = UIColor.White,
         Frame = new CGRect(0,20,UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width, height),
     };


     UIButton backBtn = new UIButton() {

         Frame = new CGRect(20, height-44, 40, 44),
         Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(18),

     } ;
     backBtn.SetTitle("Back", UIControlState.Normal);
     backBtn.SetTitleColor(UIColor.Blue, UIControlState.Normal);
     backBtn.AddTarget(this,new Selector("GoBack"),UIControlEvent.TouchUpInside);

     UILabel titleLabel = new UILabel() {
        Frame=new CGRect(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width/2-75, 0,150, height),
        Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(20),
        Text = "xxx",
        TextColor = UIColor.Black,
        Lines = 0,

     };

      UILabel line = new UILabel() {

         Frame = new CGRect(0, height, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width, 0.5),
         BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black,

      };

      backView.AddSubview(backBtn);
      backView.AddSubview(titleLabel);
      backView.AddSubview(line);

      View.AddSubview(backView);
  }


  double IsiphoneX()
  {

      double height = 44;

      if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(11, 0))
      {
         if (UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate.GetWindow().SafeAreaInsets.Bottom > 0.0)
          {
             height = 64;
          }
      }

      return height;
   }

  [Export("GoBack")]
  void GoBack()
  {
     NavigationController.PopViewController(true);
  }

  public override void ViewWillDisappear(bool animated)
  {
     base.ViewWillDisappear(animated);

     NavigationController.NavigationBar.Hidden = false;
  }

}
```

You can set the property of title , backButton and navigationBar as you need (such as text , color ,BackgroundColor ,font e.g.) .

In addition , because iOS 13.0 is release not long ago,there are still some existing issue and new features .

Comment: Zhang  this piece of code I can use for any view controller classes but I am setting at app delegate class while launching the application.suppose I have login screen and while clicking on sign in button showing activity indicator as a UIView full screen for showing loading message in that case how can I change the color of navigation bar.

Comment: Before iOS 13 I was using this piece of code {
                UINavigationBar.Appearance.BarTintColor = Utility.ColorConstants.NavigationBarColor;
                UINavigationBar.Appearance.TintColor = UIColor.White;
                UINavigationBar.Appearance.SetTitleTextAttributes(new UITextAttributes
                {
                    TextColor = UIColor.White
                });

                UIBarButtonItem.Appearance.SetTitleTextAttributes(new UITextAttributes
                {
                    TextColor = UIColor.White
                }, UIControlState.Normal);

Comment: Edit your question about the logic of login . Not the customize navigation bar .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200808/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-nawnit).